# Why do i have to return from a function that switches on an enum and covers every possible entry?

Tags: java, switch-statement, return

Say I have the following enum definition:

```java
enum SaveResult {
    Saved,
    Failed,
    EncryptionError
}
```

I then have a function that returns a `SaveResult`

```java
public SaveResult save() {
  . . .
}
```

I then have a function that returns a `boolean` based on the result of the `save()` function:

```java
public boolean doSomething() {
    SaveResult result = this.save();

    switch (result) {
        case Saved:
            return true;
        case Failed:
            return false;
        case EncryptionError:
            return false;
    }

    // Why am i still required to provide `default` case
    // for the switch or a return call at the end of the
    // function if all cases for the switch have already
    // been covered?
    //
    // The error I'm getting is "Missing return statement".
}
```

Comment: Additional enumerators could be added without recompilation of `doSomething()`.

Comment: Note that a `default` case is no longer required for enums when using the [updated switch](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354) in Java 12 and later.

Comment: The same reason this does not compile: `public boolean test() { if(true) return true; }`. Even if logically there is only one path, the compiler will evaluate the impossible path.

Comment: I don’t know how hypothetical your example is, but the `switch` could be replaced with `return result == SaveResult.Saved;`.